# Product Rule of Counting

Tags: combinatorics

I am new to combinatorics and I'm reading it from Kenneth H.Rosen book. Under the topic  Product rule of counting, this problem was given :

> A new company with just two employees, Sanchez and Patel, rents a
>   floor of a building with 12 offices. How many ways are there to assign
>   different offices to these two employees?

The answer is 12*11=132 ways

By the definition of product rule,

> Suppose that a procedure can be broken down into a sequence of two
>   tasks. If there are n 1 ways to do the first task and for each of
>   these ways of doing the first task, there are n 2 ways to do the
>   second task, then there are n 1. n 2 ways to do the procedure.

So I think it should be 12(for Sanchez) * 12(for Patel) =144.

Please explain what mistake I was doing in a detailed manner. Thank You.

Comment: The question said **different** offices. If there were the possibility of sharing, it would be $(12)(12)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! very foolish of me to miss that word. Thanks again :)

Comment: You are welcome. Combinatorial problems can be very sensitive to exact wording.  Here we imagined S being assigned her office first. For *every way* of assigning an office to S, there are $11$ ways to assign an office to P.  Later there will be a more symmetric way of visualizing. There are $\binom{12}{2}$ ways to choose $2$ offices from $12$, and for each way there are $2!$ ways to assign the chosen offices, for a total of $\binom{12}{2}2!$. This simplifies to $(12)(11)$.

Answer (score 2):

You count the office you've given to Sanchez as a possibility for Platel, something you shouldn't do as the question states that there are different offices.

Answer (score 1):

Sanchez and Patel cannot rent the same office. So, while Sanchez has 12 choices, Patel has only 11.